# Objective C: Modify Label with name containing string

Tags: ios, iphone, string, label

I want to modify a label in **objective C** like this:

When pushing a button named "Car" I want the label "pushedCar" to unhide.
Right now it looks like this but its static...

```
if ([buttonName isEqualToString:@"Car"]) {
        self.pushedCar.hidden = NO;}
```

How can I write something like:

```
if ([buttonName isEqualToString:@"Car"]) {
        self.pushed%@.hidden , buttonName = false;}
```

It's kind of a stupid example but I need it for something too complex to write down here.

Thanks in advance.

Michael

Comment: It's not clear what you're wanting here. Can you improve your example? Or describe what your example is supposed to do.

Comment: You want to change the button Name ?

Comment: Edited to lower-case buttonName. Don't use capitals for properties/ivars, it's just confusing.

Comment: Ok I'll try to make it more clear.
I have a button that looks like a house and a button that looks like a car. I want the user to click on one of the buttons. 
If he pushes the house I want a label called "pushedhouse" to appear.
If he pushes car I want "pushedcar" to appear.

Now I want want to make the Label appear with the name "pushedbuttonname". How can I bring in the name of the button I pressed and make the label that belongs to it appear?

I'll try Thilina Hewagama Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all your button titles like, Car, Van , Bus etc.
then make this as touch up inside method of all them,

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(UIButton *) pressedButton{
    NSString *buttonName = pressedButton.titleLabel.text;
    UILabel *label = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pushed%@", buttonName]];
    label.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
if ([ButtonName isEqualToString:@"Car"]) {
        self.pushedCar.hidden = !self.pushedCar.hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use KVC

```
id name = nil
if(myButtonCurrentTitle isEqualTo:@"Car"]) name = @"Car";


assert(name);
UILabel *label = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pushed%@", name]];
assert([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "How could I get an object that is related to a string" it would probably be simplest to put the buttons into an NSDictionary so you could do something like

```
MyButton *button = [buttonDict objectForKey:@"Car"];
```

but to be honest, your example code doesn't make much sense so I'm finding it hard to know how to write a decent example for you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want different buttons and labels (e.g. car, horse, cat).

In that case make an NSDictionary with the key being the buttonName (@"Car") and the the object for it the label.

You can write then something like:

```
UILabel *label = [myDictionary objectForKey:buttonName];
label.hidden = NO; // or label.hidden = !label.hidden;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use [Key Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) to get the button instance based on some arbitrary string.

You firstly need to expose the button instances using properties:

```
@interface MyClass : UIView
{
    // These are connected using Interface Builder
    IBOutlet UIButton *carButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *busButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *bikeButton;
}

@property (string, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *carButton;
@property (string, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *busButton;
@property (string, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *bikeButton;

@end
```

And you can get the instance of the button using:

```
NSString *thing = "@car";
UIButton *button = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Button", thing]];
[button setHidden:YES];
```